# Best way to create WCF "server side code" service from existing WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have an existing wsdl and xsd files. Now,  i want to create WCF "server side code" service based on existing WSDL.
I know that svcutil.exe generates host (client side) code. I don't want client side. Please, could any one help me ?.

Comment: WSDL is an XML format for describing network services as a set of endpoints operating on messages containing either document-oriented or procedure-oriented information. It wouldn't contain the Server Side Code. If you need the Server Side Code, you need to use Disassembler on a DLL.

Comment: You need to use Disassembler on the WCF Service Library. Reflector: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/; ILSpy http://ilspy.net/; DotPeek https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the client would result in a very specific wsdl file he gave me with other xsd files where the class definition is. I just want the structure of the interface headers (System.SerializableAttribute, XmlTypeAttribute ...) because DataContract and DataMember not given results in the wsdl file.
when I use svcutil, I just aligned a little bit with the wsdl file but differences remain as binding, port name. also things prefix like "intf" instead of "tns".

Comment: When I used svcutil, I just aligned a little bit with the wsdl file but differences remain as binding, port name and others. also things like prefix "intf" instead of "tns" and others.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`xsd /c /l:cs /n:Namespace.You.Want FilenameRequest.xsd FilenameResponse.xsd`

to generate c# classes with the agreed XML contract. You will have something like `ResponseClass.cs` and `RequestClass.cs`

Then create your service passing generated Request class as message parameter. Forcing service to use *XmlSerializer* instead of *DataContractSerializer*. Something like this:

```
[ServiceContract, XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, 
    Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract()]
    ResponseClass YourRequestOperation(
        [MessageParameter(Name="NameInAgreedContract")] RequestClass rq);
}
```

Then create an implementation of the interface. Deploy it. Profit.